# How to strike any letter using Unicode in Java

Tags: java, unicode

In my Java application I want to output striked letters (like html tag  do). Is there any way to do this using Unicode (combine )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. While there is the concept of a [stroke as diacritic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bar_%28diacritic%29), it's not available as a separate Unicode character, probably because the various letters that use a stroke diacritic do not place it at the same height or even angle. So the result would not resemble strikethrough markup anyway.

To output strikethrough text in Java, you need to use an output format that allows you to use explicit markup. If you have a Swing app, you're in luck as many Swing components [support HTML](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html). Otherwise it depends on what presentation technology you're using.

Comment: You’ve given a good answer why the WITH STROKE code points have no decompositions that include any sort of stroke combining character, like **ø** U+00F8 `LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH STROKE` or **đ** U+0111 `LATIN SMALL LETTER D WITH STROKE` (not to be confused with **ð** 00F0 `LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH`).  Interestingly, these *are* considered “the same letters” as **o** and **d** respectively and yes even in the ETH, as shown by the UCA DUCET. So a primary-strength UCA would count them as the base chars they don’t decompose to.

Comment: Unicode does actually define a combining strikethrough character as a separate codepoint, at U+0336.

Comment: @tchrist : OP was not looking for _letters with stroke_ (like ĐđØø etc), but for <s>strikethrough</s> that can be happily simulated using U+0336 as other answers state.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [U+0336](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0336/index.htm), the *combining long stroke overlay*, to accomplish this task.

The official [Combining Diacritical Marks](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf) unicode chart lists "strikethrough" as an 'informative alias', meaning that this is is the official specified purpose of this character.

```
0336 ̶◌ COMBINING LONG STROKE OVERLAY
       = strikethrough
       • connects on left and right
```

For comparison, here is U+0336 compared to the html `<strike>` tag:

> U̶n̶i̶c̶o̶d̶e ̶c̶o̶m̶b̶i̶n̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶l̶o̶n̶g̶ ̶s̶t̶r̶o̶k̶e̶ ̶o̶v̶e̶r̶l̶a̶y̶
> <strike>Hypertext strike tag</strike>

Note that many font rendering engines do not render U+0336 correctly, and when possible one should use markup formatting or another mechanism. Depending on your browser, the above text likely has a large gap in the line around the "m" in combining, and @Alex78191 reports that it renders so low for them that it looks more like an underline than a strikethrough.
For this reason, one should still prefer HTML another markup technology over U+0336 for this purpose, given the option.

Comment: it looks like underline

Comment: @Alex78191 Thank you for the information, I've added your observation to my answer. Unfortunately, most font renderers have only incomplete or flawed support for combining characters.

Answer (score 2):

As said before, Unicode doesn't do that, but a lot of Swing components understand basic HTML tags.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html><s>My stroke</s></html>")
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Unicode does not define a combining strikeout mark. Unicode's view is that this is the job of markup -- like HTML.

Comment: This is precisely wrong - Unicode DOES define a combining strikeout mark, as I discuss in my answer.